# Jest & jquery returning odd result

Tags: jquery, jestjs

I have html structure that I wanted to test against in jest js using jquery and it seems to be giving me an odd return on something simple.

When I do a console.log on 
`console.log("element = ", element.data('authorized'));` it shows as undefined which is not the case. 
Also what is weird is when I do a log on just element I get

```
{ '0': HTMLSelectElement {}, length: 1 }
```

Instead of an array with the jquery element itself. Anyone know why this might be happening in Jest.js

```
jest.dontMock('jquery');
window.$ = require('jquery');

test('temp test', ()=> {


    const selectEl =
        '<div id="network">'+
            '<div class="select-wrap">'+
                '<select tabindex="1" id="select-box">'+
                '<option value="C" selected="selected" data-authorized="false">Option 1</option>'+
                '<option value="D" data-authorized="false">Option 2</option>'+
                '</select>'+
            '</div>'+
        '</div>';

     document.body.innerHTML = selectEl;
     const element = $('#select-box');
    console.log("element = ", element.data('authorized'));

})
```

Comment: Ive even tried $(document).ready(function(){  }); but that doesn't work either. Anyone got an answer for this it's driving me crazy.

Comment: Anyone out there to help on this ?